# Why .addSubView(...) method resets other objects positions when used?

Tags: ios, swift

When a button at my app is pressed, it calls `addSubView()` to add a new view in the superView of my ViewController. The problem is that a have 2 buttons to move 2 other views of 100x100 at this same superView, and when i call addSubView(newView), the positions of my other 2 views reset to the origin point.

My question is, how can i add a newView preserving the other views coordinates?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bloco1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bloco2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var botao1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var botao2: UIButton!

    var bloco1Origem: CGPoint!
    var bloco2Origem: CGPoint!
    var corBlocos: UIColor!
    var reprodutorDeAudio: AVAudioPlayer?
    var somDoAlerta: NSURL!
    var novaView: UIView!
    var qntBlocosNovos = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SomDeColisão", ofType: "mp3")
        somDoAlerta = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)    
        do {
            reprodutorDeAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: somDoAlerta)
            reprodutorDeAudio!.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print(error)        
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        bloco1.backgroundColor = corBlocos
        bloco2.backgroundColor = corBlocos
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        bloco1Origem = bloco1.frame.origin
        bloco2Origem = bloco2.frame.origin
    }

    @IBAction func AddNovoBloco(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        novaView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        novaView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        self.view.addSubview(novaView)
        //self.view.didAddSubview(novaView)
        ++qntBlocosNovos
    }

    @IBAction func botao(sender: UIButton) {
        bloco1.frame.origin.x += 10
        if colisao() {
            bloco2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            botao1.enabled = false
            botao2.enabled = false
         }
//       view2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10)
    }

    @IBAction func excluirTodos(sender: UIButton) {
        while qntBlocosNovos > 0 {        
            (view.subviews.last! as UIView).removeFromSuperview()
            --qntBlocosNovos 
        }
    }

    @IBAction func botao2(sender: UIButton) {
        if qntBlocosNovos > 0 {    
            (view.subviews.last! as UIView).removeFromSuperview()
        }
        bloco2.frame.origin.x -= 10
        if colisao() {        
            bloco1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            botao1.enabled = false
            botao2.enabled = false
        }
    }

    func colisao() -> Bool {
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(bloco1.frame, bloco2.frame) {
            guard let rep = reprodutorDeAudio else {
                return true            
            }
            rep.play()
            return true 
        }
        return false
    }

    @IBAction func Reinicia(sender: UIButton) {
        bloco1.frame.origin = bloco1Origem
        bloco2.frame.origin = bloco2Origem
        botao1.enabled = true
        botao2.enabled = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Autolayout* is running and moving your views.  There are 2 ways you can deal with this:

1) Define your `bloco1` and `bloco2` views entirely in code.  Don't define them in *Interface Builder* and don't use `@IBOutlets`.  If you do this, *Autolayout* will not touch your views and they will stay where you put them.

2) If you want to define your views with *Interface Builder*, then you should not move them by altering their frames.  Instead, you should create `@IBOutlet`s to the constraints which position the views, then move the views by altering the `constant` property of the layout constraints.

To create the `@IBOutlet` to a constraint, find the constraint in the *Document Outline* view, and <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from that constraint to the *ViewController* in the code.  Give it a name like `centerXConstraint`.  It will appear in the code like this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then to move the view, just update the `constant` property:

```
    centerXConstraint.constant += 10
```